# PreparedStatement batch not performing as well as plain Statement

Tags: java, mysql, performance, jdbc

I'm writing the data access code to batch operations up to increase performance of my app.

I'm doing deletes at the moment, but this could easily apply to inserts and updates.

I have 5 tables to deal with. These are the two ways I tried (helper functions are at the bottom):

```
public void deleteFooList(final int[] fooIds)
        throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement childStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM child WHERE fooId = ?");
        PreparedStatement otherStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM otherfoo WHERE fooId = ?");
        PreparedStatement userStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM userfoo WHERE fooId = ?");
        PreparedStatement modStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM modification WHERE fooId = ?");
        PreparedStatement fooStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "DELETE FROM foo WHERE id = ?");
        for (int fooId : fooIds) {
            childStatement.setInt(1, fooId);
            otherStatement.setInt(1, fooId);
            userStatement.setInt(1, fooId);
            modStatement.setInt(1, fooId);
            fooStatement.setInt(1, fooId);
            childStatement.addBatch();
            otherStatement.addBatch();
            userStatement.addBatch();
            modStatement.addBatch();
            fooStatement.addBatch();
        }
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(childStatement, fooIds.length);
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(otherStatement, fooIds.length);
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(userStatement, fooIds.length);
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(modStatement, fooIds.length);
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(fooStatement, fooIds.length);

        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

And I also tried this:

```
public void deleteFooList2(final int[] fooIds)
    throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder deleteChildSql = new StringBuilder(
            "DELETE FROM child WHERE fooId IN (");
    StringBuilder deleteOtherSql = new StringBuilder(
            "DELETE FROM otherfoo WHERE fooId IN (");
    StringBuilder deleteUserSql = new StringBuilder(
            "DELETE FROM userfoo WHERE fooId IN (");
    StringBuilder deleteModSql = new StringBuilder(
            "DELETE FROM modification WHERE fooId IN (");
    StringBuilder deleteFooSql = new StringBuilder(
            "DELETE FROM foo WHERE id IN (");
    Connection connection = childSource.getConnection();

    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        for (int x = 0; x < fooIds.length; x++) {
            if (x > 0) {
                deleteChildSql.append(",");
                deleteOtherSql.append(",");
                deleteUserSql.append(",");
                deleteModSql.append(",");
                deleteFooSql.append(",");
            }
            deleteChildSql.append(fooIds[x]);
            deleteOtherSql.append(fooIds[x]);
            deleteUserSql.append(fooIds[x]);
            deleteModSql.append(fooIds[x]);
            deleteFooSql.append(fooIds[x]);
        }
        deleteChildSql.append(")");
        deleteOtherSql.append(")");
        deleteUserSql.append(")");
        deleteModSql.append(")");
        deleteFooSql.append(")");
        statement.addBatch(deleteChildSql.toString());
        statement.addBatch(deleteOtherSql.toString());
        statement.addBatch(deleteUserSql.toString());
        statement.addBatch(deleteModSql.toString());
        statement.addBatch(deleteFooSql.toString());
        executeBatchAndCheckResult(statement, fooIds.length);
        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }
```

Using this helper function, included for completeness rather than relevance:

```
private void executeBatchAndCheckResult(Statement statement,
                                        int count)
        throws SQLException {
    int[] results = statement.executeBatch();
    if (results == null) {
        throw new SQLException(
                "Batch update failed to return results!");
    }
    int total = 0;
    for (int result : results) {
        total += result;
        if (result == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {
            String sql = statement.toString();
            throw new SQLException(String.format(
                    "Error executing batch: %s", sql));
        }
    }
    log.info(String.format("Ran batch, statement count %d, row count %d",
            results.length, total));
    if (results.length != count) {
        throw new SQLException(String.format(
                "Batch update failed to execute correct count! " +
                        "(%d instead of %d)", results.length, count));
    }
}
```

I was surprised to find that the plain `Statement` performed a lot quicker than the set of 5 `PreparedStatements`. In fact it was out of sight. The `Statement` was just as fast as one of the 5 `PreparedStatements` on its own. Am I implementing the `PreparedStatement` batches wrongly?

This is the fast SQL from the `Statement`:

```sql
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id IN (52000,52001,52002,52003,52004,52005,52006,52007,52008,52009,52010) 
DELETE FROM modification WHERE fooId IN (52000,52001,52002,52003,52004,52005,52006,52007,52008,52009,52010) 
DELETE FROM userfoo WHERE fooId IN (52000,52001,52002,52003,52004,52005,52006,52007,52008,52009,52010) 
DELETE FROM otherfoo WHERE fooId IN (52000,52001,52002,52003,52004,52005,52006,52007,52008,52009,52010) 
DELETE FROM childfoo WHERE fooId IN (52000,52001,52002,52003,52004,52005,52006,52007,52008,52009,52010)
```

and this is the slow SQL from the `PreparedStatements`:

```sql
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id = 52010
DELETE FROM modification WHERE fooId = 52010 
DELETE FROM userfoo WHERE fooId = 52010
DELETE FROM otherfoo WHERE fooId = 52010     
DELETE FROM childfoo WHERE fooId = 52010
```

This is from P6Spy so it is not exactly what is happening. The logging from the `PreparedStatements` is just showing the last item added to the batch, not all the `DELETE`s.

I do have MySQL JDBC parameter `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` on, so I am assuming that the MySQL Connector/J is rewriting the batches to something similar like

```sql
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id = 52010 OR id = 52009 OR id = 52008 OR id = 52007 OR id = 52006 OR id = 52005 etc
```

or maybe it's not? What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You should be using foreign keys with cascade options instead of trying to delete things manually.

Comment: in the database? or are you talking about a JPA framework?

Comment: In the database of course.

Comment: just re-wrote a bunch of stored procs as Java to get rid of the db dependency - not sure that idea would fly. very custom MySQL I presume.

Comment: Foreign keys with cascade options are standard SQL and supported by most databases. You just delete from the parent table and the record in the child is deleted automatically (assuming an `on delete cascade` option).

Comment: OK, good point. I'm going to redefine the question because I am still very interested in the PreparedStatement issue.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Or at least tell us if there are any `FOREIGN KEYs`, especially of the `CASCADE` type.

Comment: The `IN(...)` format is the fastest since it incurs the least overhead for processing the statement(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do have MySQL JDBC parameter `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` on, so I am assuming that the MySQL Connector/J is rewriting the [DELETE] batches

No, it isn't. `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` only works with `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` batches. A batch of `DELETE ... WHERE fooId = ?` statements will still send each DELETE statement individually. (Confirmed by testing and inspecting the general log.) That is why you are seeing the performance difference between the PreparedStatement batch and your Statement (which has been manually optimized to delete multiple rows in a single round-trip).

Comment: Could it be because of clients side preparation which is default, rather than server side?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - A quick test suggests not. `useServerPreparedStmts=true` does not change the reluctance of `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to re-write a batch of DELETE statements; they are still sent individually.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking about converse. useServerPreparedStmts=false, does always lead to statements(delete, insert etc.) sent individualy. With parsing happening at client side?

Comment: @MangatRaiModi - `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` appears to always rewrite `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` batches and never rewrite `DELETE` batches, regardless of the `useServerPreparedStmts` setting. In fact, `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` *and* `useServerPreparedStmts=true` together can actually slow things down by sending `prepare` calls for the original command text which never get used if the INSERT batch is rewritten.